# Cycles Normal Map Baking

Tags: cycles-render-engine, normals

How do I bake from multires in cycles? I tried with a high poly copy (selected to active) but it turned out like this

[image]

Comment: What is the size of the object?

Comment: About 12 units tall

Comment: Its way too big, scale it down to actual human size or try to increase Ray Distance in bake settings

Comment: Its still showing up a little. Can you walk me through how to normal map bake in cycles?